# Dataset not getting filled

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have a simple search page in ASP.NET page where I am filling dataset based on SQL Query.

```
            con.Open();    
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    da.Fill(ds, "Emp");
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Label2.Text = "Data not found";

            }
            con.Close();
```

But even the search item exists, I get this result as "Data Not found".. Why isn't it executing if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others suggested you need to move a line of code like so:

```
        con.Open();    
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Emp");   // SEE THIS LINE!
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Label2.Text = string.Empty;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            Label2.Text = "Data not found";

        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.. One more problem.. When I enter value that is present in table, it returns values.. When I enter value in TextBox that is not in the DB table, I get message saying- "No data found" but the GridView of previous Search is still present there..

Comment: See my updated answer to resolve your second issue! (And vote the answer up!) ;o)

Comment: Worked thanks a lot.. One last doubt here.. When I enter irrelevant text, it gives "No data found" error.. Now when I entered Java which is present in the DB table, it overlaps with the previous message..

Comment: I ticked your post as correct answer.. Wish I had 15 reputations to give you an up-vote :)

Comment: Ah no worries sorry didn't spot your rep - check my update answer again to fix your final issue!

Comment: @bUkaneer.. You're a very humble person.. Thank you so very much bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
dataadapter.fill(ds)
```

Comment: You can do that as well, can you pls accept the answer if it has solved ur problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely not working because you already executed the query prior to trying to fill the dataset.  Try removing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();.  Also, a Non Query command doesn't return any results.  Make sure that your query actually does return results.

Comment: Well, the code does get executed if I remove if else condition. It was working.. When I implemented if..else, "if" condition is not working..

Answer (score 0):

hi please Try this its Working for my gridview

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConectionString"].ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Tbl_Employee", con);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    gv1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    gv1.DataBind();
                }
            }
```